# How to make this square in Python smaller?

Tags: python

Need to make the square smaller.

I'm so confused where the square size is. Need to make it smaller but not sure what part to change. For reference, this pygame is where a square bounces around a generated map and bounces on the walls when a beat in a song is played using a midi file. This isnt my code btw.

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, x: float = 0, y: float = 0, dx: int = 1, dy: int = 1):
        self.pos: list[float] = [x, y]
        self.dir: list[int] = [dx, dy]
        self.last_bounce_time = -100
        self.latest_bounce_direction = 0  # 0 = horiz, 1 = vert
        self.past_colors = []
        self.died = False

    def register_past_color(self, col: tuple[int, int, int]):
        for _ in range(max(Config.square_swipe_anim_speed, 1)):
            self.past_colors.insert(0, col)
        while len(self.past_colors) > Config.SQUARE_SIZE*4/5:
            self.past_colors.pop()

    def get_surface(self, size: tuple[int, int]):
        ss = int(Config.SQUARE_SIZE*4/5)
        surf = pygame.Surface((ss, ss))
        for index, col in enumerate(self.past_colors):
            y = index if self.dir_y != 1 else ss-1-index
            pygame.draw.line(surf, col, (0, y), (ss, y))
        return pygame.transform.scale(surf, size)

    def copy(self) -> "Square":
        new = Square(*self.pos, *self.dir)
        new.last_bounce_time = self.last_bounce_time
        new.latest_bounce_direction = self.latest_bounce_direction
        return new

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.pos[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.pos[1]

    def title_screen_physics(self, bounding: pygame.Rect):
        self.reg_move()
        r = self.rect
        if r.right > bounding.right:
            self.dir[0] = -1
            self.latest_bounce_direction = 0
        elif r.left < bounding.left:
            self.dir[0] = 1
            self.latest_bounce_direction = 0
        elif r.bottom > bounding.bottom:
            self.dir[1] = -1
            self.latest_bounce_direction = 1
        elif r.top < bounding.top:
            self.dir[1] = 1
            self.latest_bounce_direction = 1
        else:
            return False
        self.last_bounce_time = get_current_time()
        return True

    def draw(self, screen: pygame.Surface, sqrect: pygame.Rect):
        if self.died:
            return
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), sqrect)
        square_color_index = round((self.dir_x + 1)/2 + self.dir_y + 1)
        self.register_past_color(get_colors()["square"][square_color_index % len(get_colors()["square"])])
        sq_surf = self.get_surface(tuple(sqrect.inflate(-int(Config.SQUARE_SIZE/5), -int(Config.SQUARE_SIZE/5))[2:]))
        screen.blit(sq_surf, sq_surf.get_rect(center=sqrect.center))

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val: int):
        self.pos[0] = val

    @y.setter
    def y(self, val: int):
        self.pos[1] = val

    @property
    def dir_x(self):
        return self.dir[0]

    @property
    def dir_y(self):
        return self.dir[1]

    @property
    def rect(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.x-Config.SQUARE_SIZE/2, self.y-Config.SQUARE_SIZE/2, *([Config.SQUARE_SIZE]*2))

    def obey_bounce(self, bounce: Bounce):
        # planned bounces
        self.pos = bounce.square_pos
        self.dir = bounce.square_dir
        self.latest_bounce_direction = bounce.bounce_dir
        self.last_bounce_time = bounce.time
        return

    def reg_move(self, use_dt: bool = True):
        self.x += self.dir_x*Config.square_speed*(Config.dt if use_dt else 1/FRAMERATE)
        self.y += self.dir_y*Config.square_speed*(Config.dt if use_dt else 1/FRAMERATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the square comes from this variable - Config.SQUARE_SIZE - which is imported from your Config file.

Shrink its value in the Config file and you will notice the square will be shrinked.